# Can I improve WCF OData Expand queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have an WCF DataService (v3) on top of Entity Framework 6 DbContext.

I have the following tables

- Orders
- PaymentMethods
- DeliveryMethods

Order Table has about 300000 records. Now I want to query the data. With EF I would do

```
using (var context = new OrderContext())
{
    var query = context.Orders
        .Include("PaymentMethod")
        .Include("DeliveryMethod");

    var items = query.Take(100).ToList();
}
```

This code executues in 1 sec. which is fine.

And now with DataService:

```
var context = new OrderContext(uri);
var query = context.CreateQuery<Order>()
    .Expand("PaymentMethod,DeliveryMethod")
var items = query.Take(100).ToList();
```

which will take 10 seconds. If I skip the `Expand()` it will take only 1 sec. too. So basically the Expand seems to massivly slow down the query execution and gets worse for every additional include. It also looks like it is not really related to the object count (if I change the page size to 10 or even 1000) the decrese/increse is negligible.

Any idea how to fix this?

**Update**

This is my DataService class

```
public class OrderDataService : EntityFrameworkDataService<OrderContext>
{
    protected override OrderContext CreateDataSource()
    {
        return new OrderContext();
    }

    public static void InitializeService(DataServiceConfiguration config)
    {
        config.SetEntitySetAccessRule("*", EntitySetRights.All);

        config.SetServiceOperationAccessRule("*", ServiceOperationRights.All);

        config.SetServiceActionAccessRule("*", ServiceActionRights.Invoke);

        config.DataServiceBehavior.MaxProtocolVersion = DataServiceProtocolVersion.V3;

        config.UseVerboseErrors = true;
    }
}
```

**Update 2**

I use the following libs from nuget

- EntityFramework 6.1.1
- Microsoft.Data.OData 5.6.3 (also Microsoft.Data.Services...)
- Microsoft.OData.EntityFrameworkProvider 1.0.0-beta2

Comment: Your code does not show how you are exposing your `IQueryable` it is very possible that it is relying on lazy loading to achieve your expand (if the OData Provider that is used isn't EF aware (for example the Reflection OData Provider)). This is important as there are about 5 different flavours of Wcf Data Services (Web-API WCF DS, WCF DS RIA and OData, just to name a few off the top of my head).

Comment: I am using the `EntityFrameworkDataService`

Comment: Yeah... That's broken old tech. You are actually falling back on Reflection OData provider, because that class doesn't support DbContext. There is a stupid workaround, I'll post when I get home.

Comment: That would be awsome. I just moved from `EF5 + ReflectionProvider` to `EF6 + EntityFrameworkProvider` but I also moved from a developement database with a couple of records to production so I can't tell if this problem introduced itself with EF6

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class OrderDataService : EntityFrameworkDataService<ObjectContext>
{
    protected override ObjectContext CreateDataSource()
    {
        IObjectContextAdapter context = new OrderContext();
        return context.ObjectContext;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, looked promising but didn't help :-( - In the meantime I already created an OData4 Endpoint for WebApi 2.2 - slightly faster but I suppose for other reasons. The basic problem, expand slows down the query, still exists.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this causes some pain in the head but I found the cause.

I suspected OData Expand to be the problem because Entity Framework with include behaved better but that was only because OData implicitly added an `ORDER BY ID` to my query. It turns out that the current MySQL Connector for NET generates poor sql for Include with OrderBy.

Basically this query

```
var query = context.Orders
    .Include(x => x.Paymentmethods)
    .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
    .Take(10);
```

generates a query like this

```
SELECT
`Project1`.`C1`, 
`Project1`.`id`, 
`Project1`.`name`, 
`Project1`.`paymentmethod_id`, 
`Project1`.`id1`, 
`Project1`.`name1`
FROM (SELECT
`Extent1`.`id`, 
`Extent1`.`name`, 
`Extent1`.`paymentmethod_id`, 
`Extent2`.`id` AS `id1`, 
`Extent2`.`name` AS `name1`, 
1 AS `C1`
FROM `orders` AS `Extent1`
    INNER JOIN `paymentmethods` AS `Extent2` ON
        `Extent1`.`paymentmethod_id` = `Extent2`.`id`) AS `Project1`
 ORDER BY 
`Project1`.`id` ASC LIMIT 10
```

which queries all rows to do an order by on a temporary table with filesort. For Sql Server the Query will just be a simple

```
SELECT TOP (10) 
[Extent1].[id] AS [id], 
[Extent1].[name] AS [name], 
[Extent1].[paymentmethod_id] AS [paymentmethod_id], 
[Extent2].[id] AS [id1], 
[Extent2].[name] AS [name1], 
FROM  [orders] AS [Extent1]
LEFT OUTER JOIN [paymentmethods] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[paymentmethod_id] = [Extent2].[id]
ORDER BY [Extent1].[id] ASC
```

which performes much better